# Is there any way to correct this authentication problem?

Tags: ios, swiftui, google-drive-api

I am trying to implement a connection of my application in SwiftUI with Google Drive. I have created the project in Google and I already have the client ID, but when I authenticate, I get this message:

> Thread 1: "uiDelegate must either be to |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.

I am using Xcode 15.1 and Swift 5.9.2.

I try to do the authentication from the contentview.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import GoogleSignIn

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var googleDriveManager = GoogleDriveManager()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if googleDriveManager.isSignedIn {
                Text("Usuario autenticado")
            } else {
                Button("Iniciar sesión con Google") {
                    googleDriveManager.authenticate()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // Establecer el uiDelegate al rootViewController
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController as? UIViewController as? any GIDSignInUIDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

The app stops working when I press the button and I get the error mentioned.